# How to get product price from web page?

Tags: c#, web, httpwebrequest, html-agility-pack, httpwebresponse

I pull the html code from the web page but the price is not in the html code. Can you help me?

[Screenshot](https://i.imgyukle.com/2019/07/20/ktgLKU.png)

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb web = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("https://www.ceptesok.com/powerball-tablet-60li");
string html = doc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml;
```

Comment: You should ask the site owners.  They probably use an api call.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the site owner has posted the price. If it's dynamic you can see it by just doing the inspect element but if it's coming as a dynamic data(from database) then you cannot see it.